# Java - How to know when thread is waiting?

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there any neat solution of knowing when a thread has been put into `wait` status? I am putting threads to `wait` and I `notify` them when i need it. But sometimes I want to know if a thread is currently waiting, and if so, I have to do something else.

I could probably set a flag myself to true/false. But I can't imagine there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The method `getState()` of a thread returns a `Thread.State` which can be:

NEW, RUNNABLE, BLOCKED, WAITING, TIMED_WAITING or TERMINATED

See [Thread.State](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html).

Comment: Of course, by the time the method has returned the state may have changed.

Comment: Is this generally good practice to poll a thread's state like this?

Comment: @JonathanNeufeld depends on what you want to do, but no polling in general is not a good idea

Comment: @alexander.egger yes I think I would agree, I just recently came across an issue in some application code that makes me think any blocking whatsoever in the main UI thread is simply wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at [Thread.getState](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getState%28%29)?

Answer (score 4):

Check

- [public Thread.State getState()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getState%28%29)
- [Thread.State.WAITING](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#WAITING)

[Thread.State: Differences between BLOCKED vs WAITING](http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2008/07/threadstate-in-java-blocked-vs-waiting.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can have all info that you want using the ThreadMXBean.

Try this code:

```
package com.secutix.gui.seatmap;

import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.ThreadInfo;
import java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean;

public class ThreadStatus {

    private static final ThreadMXBean mbean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            buildAndLaunchThread(i);
        }

        Thread t = new Thread(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true){
                    printThreadStatus();
                    try {
                        sleep(3000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }

        };
        t.setName("detector");
        t.start();

    }

    protected static void printThreadStatus() {
        ThreadInfo[] infos = mbean.dumpAllThreads(true, true);

        for (ThreadInfo threadInfo : infos) {
            System.out.println(threadInfo.getThreadName() + " state = " + threadInfo.getThreadState());
        }

    }

    private static void buildAndLaunchThread(int i) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true){
                    try {
                        sleep(3000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }

        };
        t1.setName("t" + i);
        t1.start();

    }
}
```