# How can I test a blocking method using junit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have a class with a method that blocks and would like to validate that it is blocking. The method is as shown below.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    // the main routine is only here so I can also run the app from the command line
    applicationLauncherInstance.initialize();

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            if (null != application) {
                applicationLauncherInstance.terminate();
            }
        }
    });

    try {
        _latch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        log.warn(" main : ", e);
    }
    System.exit(0);
}
```

How can I write a unit test for such a method. I am stuck before starting.

```
public class ApplicationLauncherTest extends TestCase {


    public void testMain() throws Exception {
        ApplicationLauncher launcher = new ApplicationLauncher();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you wouldn't check whether a method call blocks in a unit test. Unit tests are more of a - "validate that some postconditions are established"-thing. Nevertheless, assuming you want to check whether a method is blocking, why can't you run the method in a new thread an [check whether the thread is blocked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1825654/4041697)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to Kulu, I found the solution.

```
public void testMain() throws Exception {
    Thread mainRunner = new Thread(() -> {
        ApplicationLauncher.main(new String[]{});
    });

    mainRunner.start();

    Thread.sleep(5000);

    assertEquals(Thread.State.WAITING, mainRunner.getState());
    mainRunner.interrupt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bwire's answer is a good way there, but I *highly* recommend that no
one ever use Thread.sleep() in unit tests for validation of some situation. It's impossible to get the timing right:

- If it's too short, you'll get a lotta false results (random failures, yay)
- If it's too long, you end up creating painfully slow tests over time. Don't underestimate this.

So, what's the answer? Any time you need to "sleep" to test something, instead "wait" for that to be true (constantly checking). This way:

- As soon as the condition is true, your program resumes--no wasted time.
- You can set the timeout on this "wait" to a crazy large value, to avoid random failures.

Here's a modified version of Bware's self-response...

```
public void testMain() throws Exception {
    Thread mainRunner = new Thread(() -> {
    ApplicationLauncher.main(new String[]{});
    });

    mainRunner.start();

    expectToBlock(mainRunner, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    mainRunner.interrupt();
}

private static void expectToBlock(Thread thread, long waitCount, TimeUnit waitUnits) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < waitUnits.toMillis(waitCount)) {
        if (thread.getState() == Thread.State.WAITING) {
            return;
        }
        Thread.sleep(50); // Don't hog the CPU
    }
    Assert.fail("Timed out while waiting for thread to block");
}
```

Comment: Whilst I agree with the flaws you points out, I'm not sure this code is correct.  The OP wants to assert that the code is `WAITING` for (at least) 5 seconds.  This code asserts that the code enters a `WAITING` state at any point in less than 30 seconds.

Comment: Ooof. Well, I guess it's more a response to the the title than the sample code (in which I interpreted the sleep as a stand-in for a more complex blocking action)  I guess we can vote it down to -1, but the "better practices" lesson is lost.